# Check for Access to Location Services (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, location-services

I have an iOS app that requests access to location services. It then displays events based on the users location. 
I would like to be able to check when the app is launched if the user has granted access to location services. Is this possible and if so where should I be looking for documentation?

Thanks

Comment: See [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1).

Answer (score 4):

have you looked at the docs at all?

`CLLocationManager` has a property 'authorizationStatus'